# Include html file with image using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am a newbie in website development.

here is my problem :

I have 2 HTML files. they are 'index.php' and 'header.php' . I try to include 'header.php' in to the 'index.php' using this code :

'index.php'

```
<body>
    <?php
        include("header/header.php");
    ?>
</body>
```

'header.php' contain this code :

```
<h1>Its header</h1>
<img src="img/006-tumblr.png" width="200" height="200">
```

its the folder hirearchy :

```
-index.php
  --header
    --img
       -006-tumblr.png
    -header.php
```

When I open 'index.php' , 'header.php' is included but the image is not displaying.

So how can I include 'header.php' with the image?

Comment: <img src="header/img/006-tumblr.png" width="200" height="200">

Comment: remove the `echo` from `echo include("header/header.php");` - just `include("header/header.php");`

Comment: @maniksidana thanks  in advance, its work. but is there any other way ?, so i dont need to change the img source . or is there  a way to  make the image source more dynamicly?

Comment: it can be done by `php while foreach loop` & give it variable name with table column.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius i tried it, but the result is same, the image not showing up

Comment: you made a comment that it was working... is it working or not?

Comment: you MUST NOTE ADDRESING ... in php you think SERVER-SIDE (relative/absolute) ... for the  <img  src='..... you should think CLIENT-SIDE so like @maniksidana said your img addres is allways     path_after_domain_folder/img/image_file.png

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius i was change the file path then its working . but is there any other way ?, so i dont need to change the file path?. btw sorry for  my bad english . :)

Comment: @sansan there is many ways where you don't need to change the url of image. Try to check html5 tag BASE https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp or htaccess rewrite https://serverfault.com/questions/62126/rewrite-only-images-with-htaccess or you may to prepend <?= BASE_URL ?> php variable to img src. Or you may encapsulate every image url into a function: <img src="<?= getImgSrc('img/006-tumblr.png') ?>" /> .. you should use google before SO

Comment: @Reloecc . Thanks. i use google before, but dunno the right keyword for my question.  so i try to ask it here.

Comment: It should be noted for ALL **HTML** web development that the paths should be absolute to the root domain of the website . So every single image file `src` should begin with a `/` to indicate the base root and then build from there. Therefore your header.php file should contain: `/header/img/006-tumblr.png` for the image. This will always work while the image is in that location, regardless of where the header.php is placed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The logic of including a file into another is different from linking a CSS file. When you include a PHP file, the entire code is added to the source file and then the server compiles the codes. So the image files and other resources should be addressed relative to the source document (not the included one). This logic is different in a CSS file and the resource files e.g. a background image is complied relative to the CSS file (Because a CSS may be used in different files hirearchy). So this will work:

```
<h1>Its header</h1>
<img src="header/img/006-tumblr.png" width="200" height="200"
```

**Footnote:** If you want to use header in different files with different hirearchy the solution for the question above is to set **BASEURL** for your document and setting the resource and anchores relative to the baseurl.

Comment: This is the right answer, but there's an essential detail missing: PHP includes happen _on the server_, CSS and images are loaded _on the browser_. The other differences you've mentioned all come from that - the browser doesn't know what files were used on the server.

Comment: This answer should be rewritten to outline that all resources called by the HTML code should be referenced to the root of the domain name; rather than being a relative pathing. The correct code for the img src should be `/header/img/006-tumblr.png` with the first `/` to indicate the site root.

Answer (score 0):

A good way of proceeding would be to have a folder "img" in your root public  HTML path containing all images, eventually with subfolders to separate them. The reason for that is that your main controller is launching from root. In that way, wherever you call your image file, you just have to go to `img/` in order to find it. The same logic applies to all media. So, if you intend to have video for example, you could have a main folder media with a img subfolder and a vid subfolder. This type of logic has to be defined at start of project so that you don't have to refactor in the middle of it.

Comment: It would help if you can revise your answer and add that - as I've said on other answers on this question - all image references to the local domain should begin by referencing the root domain resource at `/` and then building from that universal reference point. thus: `/header/img/006-tumblr.png`

Comment: While you are right, that was not my point. I was just advising to have a more organised file structure

Comment: Using a leading `/` means you don't need to refactor anything with reference to the location of the calling script `:-)`

Comment: /header/img/006-tumblr.png being a bad idea. If you follow that logic, you will have you image and other media files scattered around your site structure. After a time it will become a pain to remember what is where. Thus the advice. And if at some point you decide to organize the mess, it will imply some refactoring. Just saying, but i'me sure you will find something to get the last word out of this...

Comment: I think we're beating the same issue from different angles. I'm saying that regardless of specific locations -- which I read that you're discussing -- I am stating that the currently recognised best practise is that the path to said files should be root based rather than relatively based. ie; the path to images/CSS files/ JS files / etc. should all start at the domain base `/` . I understand your view is that images relating to a certain folder `/games/index.html` should be put in `/games/img/` ; I am saying that regardless of this, the pathing should start with that `/` first. Not `img/`....

Answer (score -1):

> Giving location from root directory makes image accessible from any location.

```
<?php define('WEBSITE_BASE', $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]);  ?>

<img src="<?=WEBSITE_BASE?>/header/img/006-tumblr.png" width="200" height="200">
```

*Best linking policy you should always follow to link static assets to your page so that it links wherever the item is used.*

Comment: Probably $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] gives your website url, like if you are using localhost it would link `<img src="localhost/header/img/006-tumblr.png" width="200" height="200">`